# Is the derivative of a straight line the same of a tangent line?

Tags: calculus

Sorry if I'm being too specific and for not showing an example but If you had a derivative of a straight line would the slope of the tangent line be the same as the straight line?

Comment: The derivative would be constant, and equal to the slope.  The derivative value is *not* the function itself, of course.  For instance, if $f(x) = 3 x$, its graph has a slope of 3, but the derivative is *constant* at 3.  The tangent line *is* the function, though.

Comment: Genearally, not. In some case it is. For example, the line $y=0$

Comment: Not sure what youre asking. A straight line is its own tangent, yes. A straight line has a constant slope, so the derivative of a straight line is a constant function, thus if you plotted the derivative of a straight line youd get only a horizontal line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

recall the formal (limit) definition of the derivative:

$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}$$

let $f(x) = ax + b$ where $a,b$ are real numbers.  Then

$\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
f'(x) &= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{\big(a(x + h) + b\big) - (ax + b)}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{ax + ah + b - ax - b}{h} \\
&= \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \dfrac{ah}{h} \\
&= a
\end{split}
\end{equation*}$

which is a horizontal line (generally speaking the derivative at a specific point is the slope of the tangent line at that point)  There are a couple of important things to note:

1) a line that is already horizontal will have a slope of 0 (that is $a$ = 0) so its derivative will always be 0

2) the derivative is a function of $x$ (our independent variable) so a vertical line does not have a derivative

Answer (score 1):

Yes, for this case the tangent and the given line are *the same*..Tangential contact occurs *everywhere*.

It can be verified that derivative of

$$ y= mx + c$$

results in a slope $$ \frac{dy}{dx} =m $$ as a constant everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you have a function of the form $$f(x) = mx + b,$$ (a line) then the derivative would be $$f'(x) = m,$$ meaning that the slope of the tangent line is $m$.

Answer (score 0):

The tangent line at $x_{*}$ is a straight line which touches $f(x_{*})$ and has the slope equal to the derivative $f'(x)$ at the point $x_{*}$.

The tangent line includes the point $\left(x_{*}, f(x_{*})\right)$ and has a slope given by $f'(x_{*})$.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the best linear approximation to a linear function is the function itself. Thinking about derivatives in this way will pay off in the future if you take multivariable calculus.

Answer (score 0):

For the function y =x you can can also rewrite as y = mx+b.  Where m is slope and b is y intercept.

For a tiny change in the input x, say dx, what is the change dy for the function y =mx+b?

Keeping in mind that the derivative is equal to the slope of the line tangent to the function y =mx+b at a single point.  To find the slope:  y2-y1/x2-x1.
Then:  limit as dx-->0 of (f(x+dx) -f(x))/dx = 
(mx+b+dx -(mx+b))/dx = 
dx/dx = 1 = constant

Note:  the algebra takes care of the y intercept b and the term mx, making b and mx go to zero,

Therefore dy/dx = constant
Should be read in a few different ways:
The rate of change of the function y = x at any point is a constant
or The derivative of the function y = x, d(y)/dx is a constant
or the slope of the line tangent to the function y=x at a single point is a constant.
or the increase input dx increases the change in y (dy) by a constant.

or the area under the curve, A, for  y = x is increased by d(A)for some input dx, and that d(A)is a constant.